# Minimization operator $\mu$, primitive recursive functions

Tags: functions, logic, recursive-algorithms

What is the function obtained by applying the minimization operator $\mu y$ to

$$f(x,y,z)=1-Xr$$

where $$r=\{(x,y,z) \; | \; z=yx\}$$ and $Xr$ is the characteristic function or $r$

Answer (score 1):

There may be minor differences in the definition according to the book you are reading, but $(\mu y)(f)$ is the function

$$(x,z) \mapsto \min\{y : f(x,y,z)=0\} $$

In particular,
$$ (\mu y)(f)(x,z) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x=z=0 \\
 z/x & \text{if } x\neq 0 \\
 \uparrow & \text{if } z\neq 0 \text{ and } x=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: It seems to me that you are minimizing Xr which is defined as xy=z, but i want to apply minimization to 1-Xr.

Comment: I have this:                                                                                                                  $$Xr=xy-z$$ so $$1-Xr=1-xy+z$$ therefore and applying  minimization
$$ \min\{y : 1-xy+z=0\} $$
So
$$ (\mu y)(f)(x,z) = \begin{cases} 1/x & \text{if } x \neq 0 \text{ and } z=0 \\
 (z+1)/x & \text{if } x\neq 0 \text{ and } z \neq 0 \\
 \uparrow & \text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } z \neq 1\end{cases}$$                                                   Could you tell me if im right?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted the comment. Your first line is not correct as $Xr(x,y,z)=1$ if $(x,y,z)\in r$ and $0$ otherwise, while $xy-z$ can have arbitrarily small values. This also means that $1-Xr$ can only be $0$ or $1$ and is $0$ iff $(x,y,z)\in r$. You are basically searching the minimum $y$ s.t. $(x,y,z)\in r$.

Comment: ok, it's clear now. Thank you so much!!